# Weird behavior using TextMeshPro

Tags: unity

I have a very simple scene setup. What I want to do is to create a button prefab composed of a sprite and a TextMeshPro object. When I group the sprite and the text under a GameObject, the pivot of the compound object appears very far from the center of the GameObject (please see the attachment).

I can't move the pivot of the text to the center no matter what I do.

Is this an expected behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should've created a Canvas first and then create the icon and label, then make an empty object align it between the two objects(icon & label) then drag it under the empty gameobject.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm creating a word game and there'll be lots of text on the screen at a moment. So does this mean I have to put Canvas objects everywhere?

Comment: @Élodie Petit for UI related things you only need one canvas. If that's troublesome for you, Text objects can also be a viable option

Comment: @GabrieleVierti That's how I handle the text objects now, thanks.